# ng-bootstrap : AngularJS Typeahead + database

Tags: angular, http

I am new to angularJS 4+. I am looking for a simple database driven typeahead implementation. can you please suggest me the example

[Actual](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples)

Raja K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to talk to a database you will need a backend that makes the connection and serves you a RESTful endpoint to make queries to.

Once you have that, I would strongly recommend using [Selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) instead of Typeahead, since it has a lot of features and customization, and they even have an example of using a REST API to get results.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the ng-bootstrap as a whole. can you please suggest me sample implementation

Comment: Thanks. I made it happen through example